# iOS5 setHidden UITabBarItem causing crash

Tags: ios5, storyboard, uitabbaritem

I'm using Storyboards in xcode with iOS5. I have a TabBarController with 6 tabs. Prior to the TabController a user selects a type of account A oR B, if type B is selected I would like to hide one of the tabs.

I have a subclass of UITabBarController and this piece of code works but its not quite what I want.

```
if (accountType == 2) {
     [[[[self tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setEnabled:NO];
}
```

This makes my second tab dark and unusable which is ok, but I really wanted this to work...

```
[[[[self tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:YES];
```

But it causes this error: -[UITabBarItem setHidden:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x856f490
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarItem setHidden:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x856f490'

Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not waiting with the initialization of the tabBar viewControllers until you know which type of Account your user selects? To do so use the `setViewControllers:animated:`method for e.g. as followed:

```
if (accountType == 1) {
    NSArray* controllersForTabBar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myVC1,myVC2,myVC3,myVC4,myVC5,myVC6 nil];
     [[[self tabBar] setViewControllers:controllersForTabBar] animated:YES];
}
if (accountType == 2) {
    NSArray* controllersForTabBar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myVC1,myVC2,myVC3,myVC4,myVC5, nil];
     [[[self tabBar] setViewControllers:controllersForTabBar] animated:YES];
}
```

The apple doc for this method says:

> When you assign a new set of view controllers runtime, the tab bar
>   controller removes all of the old view controllers before installing
>   the new ones. When changing the view controllers, the tab bar
>   controller remembers the view controller object that was previously
>   selected and attempts to reselect it. If the selected view controller
>   is no longer present, it attempts to select the view controller at the
>   same index in the array as the previous selection. If that index is
>   invalid, it selects the view controller at index 0.

Regarding your error message: You get that error because the tabBar doesn't implement a method `setHidden:`.

Answer (score 1):

d.ennis answer pointed me in the right direction. Have to tweak it slightly for ios5 with Storyboards...

```
// load the storyboard by name
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

if (accountType == 1) {
   UIViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
   UIViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
} else {
   UIViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
   UIViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
   UIViewController *tvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];

}    

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;

NSArray *controllersForTabBar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: fvc, svc, nil];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:controllersForTabBar animated:NO];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```